# Comparing two sound waves

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a project that I am working on that needs to compare two sound waves.

I have two sounds waves, w1 and w2. I am looping w1 and playing it on one channel. I play the sound through a device and then record it on another channel, the recorded wave being w2. I want to know if w1=w2 or if w2 contains w1. I have tried looking at the cross corelation of the two waves but this doesn't seem to help because w1 and w2 aren't neccessarly the same length.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Suggest you look into sound fingerprinting http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_fingerprint

Comment: You will need to work in the frequency domain rather than time domain, meaning you need to implement FFT (fast fourier) analysis.

Comment: yes try using a FFT (fast fourier trasnform) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform

Answer (score 0):

Not really a solution as such but you could maybe try comparing the size of the two sound files to check if they are the same, as for checking the sound waves themselves, i am not entirely sure how you would go about doing so.